# Java function doesnt work

Tags: java, http

I have a small program for inserting data into a database with http.
I made a function to do this but when i call the function in my main file it seems that it does not work. I tried debugging it but when I set a breakpoint on the line it does not show that the function is used. Can someone help me?

```
public class School_Planner {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static  void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    HTTP_Conncetion.Connect();

}   
}
```

.

```
public class HTTP_Conncetion {

public static void Connect(){
    try {
// open a connection to the site
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/HTTP_Connection/index.php");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
// activate the output
con.setDoOutput(true);
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(con.getOutputStream());
// send your parameters to your site
ps.print("firstKey=firstValue");
//ps.print("&secondKey=secondValue");

// we have to get the input stream in order to actually send the request
con.getInputStream();

// close the print stream
ps.close();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

**EDIT**
After the command of Jon Skeet, i think i have to be a little more specific. The problem i think is that the function does not work or that it skips over the function.

Comment: "it seems that it doesnt work" - we don't know what it's meant to do, or what you've observed that it *does* do. We really can't help you with so little information.

Comment: Try catching general Exception as well and see if you get any result.

Comment: Your code will _defeneitly_ call Method or throw exception.

Comment: @JonSkeet The program doesnt work because i think it skips my function

Comment: No, it definitely won't do that. But then your method doesn't really *do* anything at the moment anyway - if it worked, how would you tell? You're getting the input stream, and then ignoring it...

Comment: So when you step through the code in your debugger, what does it do?

Comment: The code is badly quoted, it's missing closing braces. You need to remove unncessary comments. Also, say something about what you are TRYING to do.  And you cannot have two public classes in the same .java file so your code block above makes no sense.

Comment: It doesnt go to the function

Comment: @AhmedMasud It isnt in the same file.

Comment: That is just as unhelpful as the first time you said, it.  Can you tell us what is *does* do.

Comment: Then show them as two different files. Also, where is your `implements` statement for the HTTP_Connections class.

Comment: It doesnt go into the function so it doesnt Connect to my http server

Comment: Are the two classes in the same package?

Comment: @inquisitor Yes they are in the same pakacge but not in the same file

Comment: try ps.close() after sending data, and then wait response.

Comment: The problem isnt that the data isnt send but that i cant enter the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code is just fine it calls the URL

```
http://localhost:8080/HTTP_Connection/index.php
```

with the parameter firstKey and its value firstValue

Unless you forgot to do the imports which would result in a compile error to begin with.
I guess your error is on the server side. Please double check the server.

For sure your question is very unspecific - no exception, no exact description of what "function" you think is not called. Not what you expect to happen and what you miss of happening. Please adjust your question in a way that there can be a more concrete answer to your question.